# Get API data for each row in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have the following data:

```
 {
     "id": 1,
     "price": 229.2,
     "product": 263,
     "plan": null, 
     "currency": 2,
     "taxrule": 1 # ID of the Taxrule
 }
```

This can also be a list of objects.

When I publish this data, I also want to fetch the relevant data for each ID. For example, I want to display the name of the Taxrule. So I want to make an API call and fetch the Taxrule with id 1 that would look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1, # ID of the Taxrule
    "name": "25% Standard",
    "percentage": 25.0
}
```

If my HTML looks like this:

```
<tr class="clickable-row" ng-repeat="pricing in pricings">
    <td>
        <span>{{pricing.price}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>{{pricing.taxrule.name}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I display `{{pricing.taxrule.name}}`? How do I make an API call to populate the data within the loop?

Comment: I think `pricings` should be an array..

Comment: What about a directive that will display your taxrule details when passed a tax rule id? Then you just inject it into your ng-repeat, it deals with getting the data and rendering it. If not you would be better of build up your model in the controller and making the API's calls there. If the latter `$q.all` may help.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be handled by the API returning the pricing data but I know we don't always have control over what we return.

If there aren't many taxrules I would suggest getting pricing and taxrules from the API in two calls. Then in your HTML filter your taxrules in an ng-repeat

```
<tr class="clickable-row" ng-repeat="pricing in pricings">
<td>
    <span>{{pricing.price}}</span>
</td>
<td>
    <span ng-repeat="taxrule in taxrules | filter:{id:pricing.taxrule}">
         {{taxrule.name}}
    </span>
</td>
```